# Matlab EPS exporting - Maximum file size / capacity?

Tags: matlab, pdf, printing, export, eps

I have a matlab code reading in vertices and faces for PATCH plotting.

The data I'm reading is basically the same in every loop... but with more details. From 1.000 vertices up to 5.000.000 vertices - But at some point the EPS file won't "grow". The maximum size of the file appears to be 6,23 MB (6.542.050 bytes).

When I'm using a "capped" file it doesn't act like an EPS file. Is there a way to increase the file 'capacity'? When I convert the capped files to PDF the quality is really bad... worse then 8bit gif file.

I've created a [One Drive Folder including two eps files and two pdf files](https://1drv.ms/f/s!AnT2xkh_keikkHlA6vsv2UDXzTtV). One of the eps files (Mesh0gs8.eps) is under the cap and the other (Mesh0gs16.eps) is capped. I also included a PDF file converted from the eps files.

I don't think the Matlab code is the problem since I'm using the exact same one for both files. But here it is...

```
function plot(R,ii,jj)

f1 = figure(10);
hold on; axis equal;

patch('Faces', R(ii,jj).faces, 'Vertices', R(ii,jj).vertices , 'FaceColor', R.colors{ii}, 'EdgeColor',R.colors{ii});


    FileName = sprintf('Mesh%2.0f.%s.eps', ii , R(ii,jj).FileName);
    print(f1,'-depsc', '-loose', FileName);
close(f1)
```

Comment: Chances are your figure `Renderer` is set to `opengl` and the resulting EPS isn't actually a true vector graphic. Try using `export_fig` from the file exchange or use the `painters` renderer instead

Comment: Thanks for you comment @Suever - I'll take a look at the render settings. Never thought of them. On quick google I found Matlab's requirements of 1GB and I'm not sure if the computer have that and I can't check since I'm connected via Remote Desktop. The computer has 128GB RAM so it should handle these kind of figures. Probably just have to make Matlab use it properly.

Comment: -Painters gave me files up to 400mb eps files resulting in 4mb pdf files. That's something I can't include in my work. I'll try the export_fig option.

Comment: How many faces/vertices are in your mesh?

Comment: The largest mesh I would like to have on .eps have 1.250.496 vertices and 2.498.821 faces (also have other much larger which I won't use). But I guess I don't really need it on .eps. That one is 145 MB (152.998.164 bytes) on .eps and when converted to .pdf for LaTeX Thesis use it is 18,1 MB (19.070.377 bytes). It is really dense and at full overview there are really nothing to see. When zooming in to section of interest the .pdf file is 1,69 MB (1.782.366 bytes) which is still pretty heavy for a single .pdf image.

Comment: Yea, with MATLAB EPS files, each edge, face, etc. is going to be a separate element in your EPS file so the size is going to be large. I would probably just save it as a high resolution PNG or another lossless image format.